# No filter for uuid in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid

I want to do a filter in SQL where no value of an `uuid` is matched. That is, a `where` condition where no row is matched by the condition.

With a regular `int4` id, I would do:

```
where my_id = -1
```

If I do the same thing with the `uuid`, I get:

```
where my_uuid = '-1'
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "-1"
```

How can I do this with an `uuid`? I would need to use a `=`, so solutions of the form

```
where my_uuid is null
```

don't work for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read the question again and add more details. For me it is not clear...

Comment: `where my_uuid is null`

Comment: `where my_uuid is null` is ok, but I am looking of a `where my_uuid = xxx` form

Comment: @DavidMasip `-1` is indeed an invalid `UUID`. Perhaps you could show a data sample from your db? Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing

Comment: I don't understand why you think `where my_id = -1` wouldn't return any rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2237f4950e688de7c719e031aaa8a9e0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid
```

That is just as good an "impossible value" as -1 is for an `integer` (both are not really impossible).